# Laravel 8 DB transaction: is a transaction unique to the controller instance or is it unique to the connection DB name?

Tags: mysql, laravel, transactions

I am relatively new to Laravel and I want to know more about the behavior of the following code inside an API controller method (i.e. defined in routes/api.php).

```
DB::connection($dbName)->beginTransaction();
```

Assuming two people simultaneously access to the server and two controller instances are created. Now both instances calls `DB::connection($dbName)->beginTransaction();)` and executes some code before commiting.

To describe the situation more clearly, two people A and B both access to the same Laravel server, with two instances of the same controller class. The two controller instances both access to the same DB from the same IP address and executes the same code segment which involves the `beginTransaction`.

As of my current information there are two possible things happening:

(1) They are treated as two different transactions and things such as lastInsertId are maintained separately. This is the desired behavior but I have trouble understanding how the two different instances of the controller are identified internally. Based on a rough look at Laravel source code it seems only read the config file for the specific DB connection, which is identical for both instances of the controller.

(2) They are treated as the same transaction, which is not the desired behavior. I will have to think of a way to make it work like described in (1)

Currently I don't have sufficient environment for accurately testing behavior of simultaneous controller instances so I have to ask the question here.

I have read https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#database-transactions but it does not tell us which of (1) or (2) it is.

Comment: Being a laravel unaware person I'd do a [select CONNECTION_ID()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connection_id/) ([mysql too](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_connection-id)) in both connections. If you end up with different numbers its (1).

Comment: each concurrent request is handled in it's own PHP thread/process and each transaction is isolated from other transactions. Each controller instance will exist within this thread/process. PHP is not like Java EE or .NET where the server is also a container for objects and therefore objects can be shared across requests

Comment: @apokryfos Thank you for the answer. Does this mean by default behavior of PHP it must be case (1) with or without Laravel?

Comment: Yes in PHP each request is an independent entity which initialises anything in its own "sandbox". There are [ways](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.shmop.php) to share information between PHP processes but they are very low level and rarely used in practice.  There are also ways to pool MySQL connections but even if you use those each time you acquire a connection from the pool it is reset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's 1st case

Transactions aren't even part of Laravel - they are part of SQL.
Laravel only calls SQL.

Also in PHP each request is handles separately by spawning a new instance of script. Therefore there is no variable sharing between two requests.